# RVM issue with not using default gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I am new to RVM. I have already run this command to set 'global' as my default gemset:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-head@global --default
```

When I start up a fresh terminal and run `rvm gemset list` I get this (which seems to show global is correctly the default):

```
gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-head (found in /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head)
   (default)
=> global
```

However, when I try running Ruby from the command line, such as `ruby -v`, I get an error that bundler isn't installed.

If I do `gem install bundler` and rerun the identical command, I get the exact same error, as if bundler isn't installed.

I then run `rvm gemset use global`, and if I run the same `rvm gemset list` I get the EXACT same output, where global seems to be the `=>` default.

But then running `ruby -v` works fine. Whats going on here?

Comment: I can't offer a solution but to get a better idea what is going on it might help to know more about the state of your system in the situations you have described above. If you use `rvm current` to list the current ruby and gemset or `which ruby` to see which ruby binary you are actually using to the results match your expectations?

Comment: its correct: ruby-1.9.3-head@global

Comment: what `echo $PATH` shows?

Comment: :/Users/john/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin